# awk: command to parse the file and compare the data with next line and print in csv format

Tags: awk

I have following i/p which is space separated.
First column is timestamp and next is thread id.

I want to o/p into a csv file

**Sample Input**

```
04/09/15,08:49:05.001210  [Dispatch#3 (0x1b3b738)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.118592  [Dispatch#0 (0x1b3b708)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.225846  [Dispatch#2 (0x1b3b728)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.361914  [Dispatch#1 (0x1b3b718)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.469372  [Dispatch#3 (0x1b3b738)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.569784  [Dispatch#0 (0x1b3b708)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.738324  [Dispatch#2 (0x1b3b728)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.851328  [Dispatch#1 (0x1b3b718)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:05.965042  [Dispatch#3 (0x1b3b738)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:06.041505  [Dispatch#0 (0x1b3b708)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:06.151353  [Dispatch#2 (0x1b3b728)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:49:07.814024  [Dispatch#1 (0xb29718)] NOTI   
04/09/15,08:49:07.588469  [Dispatch#1 (0xb29718)] NOTI   
04/09/15,08:49:07.371815  [Dispatch#0 (0xb29708)] NOTI   
04/09/15,08:49:07.160045  [Dispatch#0 (0xb29708)] NOTI   
04/09/15,08:49:07.979571  [Dispatch#0 (0xb29708)] NOTI   
04/09/15,08:50:08.385921  [Dispatch#0 (0x120e708)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:50:08.450522  [Dispatch#3 (0x120e738)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:50:08.550118  [Dispatch#1 (0x120e718)] NOTI  
04/09/15,08:50:08.600923  [Dispatch#0 (0x120e708)] NOTI
```

**o/p in csv format**

```
TimeStamp,Thread1,Thread2,Thread3,Thread4    
04/09/15 08:49:05,2,2,2,3    
04/09/15 08:49:06,1,0,1,0    
04/09/15 08:49:07,3,2,0,0    
04/09/15 08:49:08,2,1,0,1
```

So I want to print number of records processed by each thread at a particular time.

So in above example, at **04/09/15 08:49:07** thread 1 (**0x1b3b718**) has **3** records, thread 2 (**0xb29718**) has **2** records and **thread 3 & 4 don't have any records.**

Please suggest if it possible to get this through awk command.

Comment: There are more than 4 "threads" in your input - how do we know which ones go into the output?

Comment: It is possible in an awk command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, then

```
awk -F '[,.# ]+' -v OFS=, 'function ts() { return $1 " " $2 } function dump() { print saved, a[0]+0, a[1]+0, a[2]+0, a[3]+0 } BEGIN { print "TimeStamp", "Thread1", "Thread2", "Thread3", "Thread4" } ts() != saved { if(NR != 1) dump(); delete a; saved = ts() } { ++a[$5] } END { dump() }' filename
```

is a somewhat crude way to do it.

The trick is that with the field separator regex `[,.# ]+`, the lines are split so that the time stamp is in fields 1 and 2, and the thread number in field 5. The `-v OFS=,` option sets the output field separator to a comma, so that the output data is CSV. Then:

```
function ts() {       # function to build a full timestamp as it is printed
  return $1 " " $2    # later
}

function dump() {     # function to print a result line. The +0 is to force
                      # the fields to be numbers, in case one remained empty.
  print saved, a[0]+0, a[1]+0, a[2]+0, a[3]+0
}

BEGIN {               # in the beginning, print the header line.
  print "TimeStamp", "Thread1", "Thread2", "Thread3", "Thread4"
} 

ts() != saved {       # if the timestamp changed:
  if(NR != 1) dump()  # if we're not just starting, print the result for
                      # the last block
  delete a            # discard counters
  saved = ts()        # save new timestamp
}
{ ++a[$5] }           # increase the counter for the thread this line mentions
END { dump() }        # and in the end, print the result for the last block.
```

**Addendum re: comment:** For a dynamic number of threads, we'll need two passes over the file. In the first pass, we find out how many threads there are, and in the second we print. This is because the entries for the first second in the file may not tell us about all threads. Since this is becoming unwieldy for a one-liner, put the following code into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS  = "[,.# ]+"
  OFS = ","
}

function ts() {
  return $1 " " $2
}

function dump() {
  printf("%s", saved);
  for(i = 0; i <= threads; ++i) {
    printf("%s%d", OFS, a[i])
  }
  print ""
}

# NR == FNR is true only for the first pass.    
NR == FNR {
  threads = $5 > threads ? $5 : threads
  next
}

FNR == 1 {
  printf("TimeStamp");
  for(i = 0; i <= threads; ++i) {
    printf("%sThread%d", OFS, i + 1)
  }
  print "";
} 

ts() != saved {
  if(FNR != 1) {
    dump()
  }

  delete a
  saved = ts()
}
{ ++a[$5] }
END { dump() }
```

call it, say, `foo.awk`, and run

```
awk -f foo.awk filename filename
```

Note that the file name has to be given to awk **twice**. It works very nearly the same way, except that there's a pass before the printing that finds the largest thread number and that the printing is done in loops.

Comment: One more help, it is possible to have the thread dynamically identified. In the above example we have 4 threads, but we can more threads too. so instead of changing in the command can it identified from file itself?

Comment: Yes, but it'll require walking over the file twice (since the first entries may not tell us about all threads). See the edit.